# Is it possible to pass the variable value like shown inthe code snippet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to generate the random colors when the button is being clicked. May I ask please if it is the right way to generate the random color?

```js
randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
// --- more code ---
changeHeaderColor() {
  console.log("Change_header_color_was_clicked");
  this.setState({ colors: "randomColor" });
}
// --- more code ---
render() {
  return (
    <h1 style={{ color: this.state.colors }}>
      This is the header Component{" "}
      <button onClick={() => this.changeHeaderColor()}>
        Change Header Color
      </button>
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: It did not work when I click the button. May I ask what type of mistake am I doing`?

Comment: The only problem here is that you quote `randomColor` in this line: `this.setState({colors: 'randomColor'})`. There's no reason to do that, so don't.

Comment: Formatted the code to look better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this and setting it in state, because you're doing it in a static way, all you can do is, in simple terms:

```
const randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

And then use:

```
<h1 style={{color: randomColor}}>
```

You may have a simple re-render option by changing the state variable, which forces re-rendering.

**Full Code**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(0);
  const randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  const style = { color: randomColor };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Just trigger a change.
    setChange(change + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 style={style}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handleChange}>Change Colour</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo:** https://24jbd.csb.app/

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: randomColor is not defined is the error when I wrote your suggestion for styling.

Comment: @pythonbuddha Please check the complete code I provided now.

Comment: @pythonbuddha Check it out now.

Comment: may I ask please if it is possible to change color without {useState} ? I my application i have functional component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224476/discussion-between-pythonbuddha-and-praveen-kumar-purushothaman).

Answer (score -1):

The line of code that generates a random color works fine. I think your issue is in a different place.

You are setting the state to the string literal `'randomColor'`, which is not what you want. The way you have it, you are setting the color to the text/letters "randomColor". You want to set the state to the value stored in the variable named `randomColor`. Note the lack of single quotes around the variable name:

```
this.setState({colors: randomColor})
```

Comment: it gives me error: Failed to compile. 'randomColor' is not defined.

Comment: `let randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);`  Note the keyword `let` before your line of code. If the variable is not already declared, you must declare it.

Comment: thank you for your help, but the solution you are giving does not have effect.